# picasso not displaying image from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, picasso

[Link To Data Base structer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhde9.png) I recently added a feature in my app where it allows the user to upload a profile picture and that image is stored in firebase and then displayed to the user in the app. The image successfully gets stored in the firebase but when the image is going to be displayed it just removes the default display image and displays nothing.

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private DatabaseReference mUserDatabase;
private FirebaseUser mCurrentUser;


//Android Layout

private CircleImageView mDisplayImage;
private TextView mName;
private TextView mStatus;

private Button mStatusBtn;
private Button mImageBtn;

private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

private static final int GALLERY_PICK = 1;

private StorageReference mImageStorage;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    mDisplayImage = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.settings_image);
    mName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.settings_name);
    mStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.settings_status);

    mStatusBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settings_status_btn);
    mImageBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settings_image_btn);
    mImageStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

    mCurrentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    String current_uid = mCurrentUser.getUid();

    mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(current_uid);
    mUserDatabase.keepSynced(true);

    mUserDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
            String status = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();
            String image = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();

            mName.setText(name);
            mStatus.setText(status);

            if (!image.equals("default")) {
                Picasso.with(SettingsActivity.this).load(image).into(mDisplayImage);

            } else {
                Picasso.with(SettingsActivity.this).load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.goodgolden).into(mDisplayImage);
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    mStatusBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String status_value = mStatus.getText().toString();

            Intent status_intent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, StatusActivity.class);
            status_intent.putExtra("status_value", status_value);
            startActivity(status_intent);

        }
    });

    mImageBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            Intent gallaryIntent = new Intent();
            gallaryIntent.setType("image/*");
            gallaryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(gallaryIntent, "Select Image"), GALLERY_PICK);
            /*
            CropImage.activity()
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                    .start(SettingsActivity.this);
            */

        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == GALLERY_PICK && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        String imageUri = data.getDataString();

        CropImage.activity(Uri.parse(imageUri))
                .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                .start(this);

        // Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, imageUri, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog((SettingsActivity.this));
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Uploading");
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Pleas Stand By");
            mProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();

            Uri resultUri = result.getUri();

            String current_user_id = mCurrentUser.getUid();

            StorageReference filepath = mImageStorage.child("profile_images").child(current_user_id + (".jpeg"));
            filepath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        String download_url = task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString();
                        // dont know if this solution will work at 6:15 video

                        mUserDatabase.child("image").setValue(download_url).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Succesful Upload", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }

                            }
                        });


                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Error Up Loading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    }

                }
            });

        } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
            Exception error = result.getError();
        }
    }
}


07-11 20:15:12.147 30329-30329/com.example.android.lapitchat E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.android.lapitchat, PID: 30329
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Center crop requires calling resize with positive width and height.
    at com.squareup.picasso.Request$Builder.build(Request.java:496)
    at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.createRequest(RequestCreator.java:758)
    at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:709)
    at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:665)
    at com.example.android.lapitchat.SettingsActivity$1.onDataChange(SettingsActivity.java:84)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzfc.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzgx.zzdr(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzhd.run(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
```

Comment: can you post string image output ? or how your database structure is ?

Comment: added database structure image above

Answer (score 0):

Use latest version of Picasso as -

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

Picasso.get().load(url).resize(100,100).centerCrop().into(imageView);
```

Comment: i update the version of Picasso to the latest version if i use Picasso.get().load(image).centerCrop().into(mDisplayImage); the app crashes but if i use Picasso.get().load(image.into(mDisplayImage); the app does the same thing as previos stated

Comment: i am using Picasso.get().load(image).resize(100,100).centerCrop().into(mDisplayImage); like listed above but i am still encountering the same problem of the image dissapearing

Answer (score 0):

Try Replacing the code by this !!!

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private DatabaseReference mUserDatabase;
private FirebaseUser mCurrentUser;

private CircleImageView mDisplayImage;
private TextView mName;
private TextView mStatus;

private Button mStatusBtn;
private Button mImageBtn;

private static final int GALLERY_PICK = 1;

// Storage Firebase
private StorageReference mImageStorage;

private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    mDisplayImage = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.settings_image);
    mName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.settings_name);
    mStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.settings_status);

    mStatusBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settings_status_btn);
    mImageBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settings_image_btn);

    mCurrentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    mImageStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

    String current_uid = mCurrentUser.getUid();

    mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(current_uid);
    mUserDatabase.keepSynced(true);

    mUserDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
            final String image = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();
            String status = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();
            String thumb_image = dataSnapshot.child("thumb_image").getValue().toString();

            mName.setText(name);
            mStatus.setText(status);

            if(!image.equals("default")) {

                //Picasso.with(SettingsActivity.this).load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.default_avatar).into(mDisplayImage);

                Picasso.with(SettingsActivity.this).load(image).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.default_avatar).into(mDisplayImage, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {

                        Picasso.with(SettingsActivity.this).load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.default_avatar).into(mDisplayImage);

                    }
                });

            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }

    });
    mStatusBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String status_value = mStatus.getText().toString();

            Intent status_intent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, StatusActivity.class);
            status_intent.putExtra("status_value", status_value);
            startActivity(status_intent);

        }
    });

    mImageBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
            galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
            galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "SELECT IMAGE"), GALLERY_PICK);

        }
    });


}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == GALLERY_PICK && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        Uri imageUri = data.getData();

        CropImage.activity(imageUri)
                .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                .setMinCropWindowSize(500, 500)
                .start(this);

        //Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, imageUri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }


    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {

        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SettingsActivity.this);
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Uploading Image...");
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please wait while we upload and process the image.");
            mProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();


            Uri resultUri = result.getUri();

            File thumb_filePath = new File(resultUri.getPath());

            String current_user_id = mCurrentUser.getUid();


            Bitmap thumb_bitmap = new Compressor(this)
                    .setMaxWidth(200)
                    .setMaxHeight(200)
                    .setQuality(75)
                    .compressToBitmap(thumb_filePath);

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            thumb_bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            final byte[] thumb_byte = baos.toByteArray();


            StorageReference filepath = mImageStorage.child("profile_images").child(current_user_id + ".jpg");
            final StorageReference thumb_filepath = mImageStorage.child("profile_images").child("thumbs").child(current_user_id + ".jpg");



            filepath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {

                    if(task.isSuccessful()){

                        final String download_url = task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString();

                        UploadTask uploadTask = thumb_filepath.putBytes(thumb_byte);
                        uploadTask.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> thumb_task) {

                                String thumb_downloadUrl = thumb_task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString();

                                if(thumb_task.isSuccessful()){

                                    Map update_hashMap = new HashMap();
                                    update_hashMap.put("image", download_url);
                                    update_hashMap.put("thumb_image", thumb_downloadUrl);

                                    mUserDatabase.updateChildren(update_hashMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                            if(task.isSuccessful()){

                                                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                                                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Success Uploading.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                            }

                                        }
                                    });


                                } else {

                                    Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Error in uploading thumbnail.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();

                                }


                            }
                        });



                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Error in uploading.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();

                    }

                }
            });



        } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {

            Exception error = result.getError();

        }
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Instead of just dumping the fixed code, try explaining what you changed in order to solve the problem the author was having. This not only helps the author understand, but others with a similar issue might benefit too.